# Why is my claculator javascript code not working on Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

```js
document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function() {
  var p1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inpu1").value);
  var p2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inpu2").value);
  adding(p1, p2);
}

function adding(p1, p2) {
  document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "sum: " + (p1 + p2);
}
```

```html
<h1>adding</h1>
<input type="number" name="name" id="inpu1" placeholder="1st summand" /><br>
<input type="number" name="name" id="inpu2" placeholder="2nd summand" /><br>
<button name="button" id="butt">=</button>
<h3 id="add">sum:</h3>
```

So why does this code not work on mobile Safari browsers? It functions perfectly on google chrome.

Comment: It looks reasonable. What happens in Safari, any console errors? If not, have you tried adding `console.log`s to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: @mplungjan The question says "mobile".

Comment: Stack Snippets don't run in mobile browsers. I copied it to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/z87t3sqd/3/) and it works fine on my iphone.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just found the option switch to the desktop site in mobile safari.

Comment: What doesn't work? I tried it in Safari on iOS 12 and it works just fine.